# C# delegates and graphics

Tags: c#, function, delegates

Working on a problem where I need to make a program that offers you to choose from several functions; provides the ability to set the values of the coefficients a, b, and c, as well as the start and end values and steps of argument x. After clicking the Table button, a table of argument and function values is displayed.

And it has to be in a way where each function is a separate subprogram. And create a function tab method so that it can pass the selected function as a parameter.

Im making some progress, but I come across an error - 'Non-invocable member 'Form1.b' cannot be used like a method.' and I cant figure out for the life of me what Im doing wrong.

The code so far:

```
namespace MD2._5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int step;
        double xEnd, xBegin;
        double a, b, c;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        public delegate double DY(double a, double b, double c, int x); //declares delegate



        public static double Y0(double a, double b, double c, int x) //function to calculate the result
        {
            return a * (x * x) + (b * x + c);
        }

        public static double Y1(double a, double b, double c, int x)
        {
            return (a / (x * x)) + (b / x + c);
        }

        public static double Y2(double a, double b, double c, int x)
        {
            return ((a * x) + b) / ((a * x) + c);
        }



        public DY[] Y = new DY[3] { Y0, Y1, Y2 }; //Creates a array of the functions above



        private void radioButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int buttonPressed = Convert.ToInt32(((RadioButton)sender).Tag);
            DoTable(Y[buttonPressed]);
        }



        private void DoTable(DY y) //This will print the table
        {
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            richTextBox1.AppendText("    x      y ");

            double howmanylines = xEnd + xBegin;

            for (double x = howmanylines; x <= howmanylines; x += step)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText("\n    " + x.ToString() + "\t" + y(x).ToString()); //error appearing here
            }
        }





        private void step_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //sets the step int
        {
            step = Convert.ToInt32(stepText.Text);
        }

        private void x_end_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//Sets x end
        {
            xEnd = Convert.ToInt32(x_end.Text);
        }

        private void x_begin_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //sets x begin
        {
            xBegin = Convert.ToInt32(x_begin.Text);
        }

        private void textBoxA_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //sets a value
        {
            a = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxA.Text);
        }
        private void textBoxB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //sets b value
        {
            b = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxB.Text);
        }
        private void textBoxC_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //sets c value
        {
            c = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxC.Text);
        }
```

The end result should essentially look like this (numbers are drawn on as the program doesnt launch right now):

[image]

The second part is to generate a graphics version of the table, but thats for a later time as I have no idea how to go about doing that one yet..

Any pointers, criticisms or suggestions much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'Non-invocable member 'Form1.b' cannot be used like a method.'

You are getting this error because in the below line

```
 richTextBox1.AppendText("\n    " + x.ToString() + "\t" + y(x).ToString());
```

as you are invoking delegate DY as y(x) i.e. by passing one parameter, but the delegate DY expects 4 parameters a,b,c and x, since it couldn't find b it's throwing that error.

Comment: Now the issue is that I've made an error somewhere in calculations as it just give me 0's in the table and does so infinitely so it just crashes

Comment: Not sure but one issue I see is in the  double howmanylines = xEnd + xBegin; which will give you 6+-6=0 . I think it should be xEnd-xBegin